# htaccess rewrite after/with redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When there's 404 missing page error this URL is called:

`https://domain.com/404/`

Inside the 404 folder there is only a htaccess file that will redirect to language specific error pages (subfolders only with one `index.html` in them).

```
/
  404
  .htaccess
     pt
      index.html
     en
      index.html
```

htaccess file code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If Accept-Language starts with 'pt',
# then redirect (only) subdirectory 'pt'
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}pt [L,NC]

# Otherwise, redirect to en
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}en [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

The final URL looks like this for Portuguese for example: `domain.com/404/pt/`

What do I need to change so that the URL will still redirect to the index.html in the language specific subfolder but will look like  `domain.com/404`(with or without trailing slash)?

Thank you.

Comment: Redirecting 404s externally is a bad idea to begin with – because that way clients that rely on the HTTP status code information (such as f.e. search engine bots) will *not get* a status code 404 any more for the resource they originally requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For silent rewrites to language specific 404 use this .htaccess in `/404/` sub-directory:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /404/

# If Accept-Language starts with 'pt',
# then redirect (only) subdirectory 'pt'
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ pt/index.html [L]

# Otherwise, redirect to en
RewriteRule ^/?$ en/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet: browser URL reads `domain.com/404/` but reports never-ending redirect loop error and index.html from subfolder (corresponding to language) isn't loaded.

Comment: Don't have Chrome but Firefox. It shows many 302s, all for `https://domain.com/404/`

Comment: In the 404 htaccess only other language rules like the pt one.   But I discovered: when I enter `domain.com/404/` in browser I get this error `/var/www/virtual/username/domain.com/404/pt/ not found on this server`. When I enter `domain.com/404/pt/` it shows.

Comment: yes that's fine, I think you needed `RewriteBase` line to avoid full path being appended

Comment: Great. Now it works. I only need to adjust the links in the index.html and I'm all set. Thank you very much!